# How to assign javascript variable to amcharts dataloader?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, amcharts

I need to assign a javascript variable to amcharts dataloader. but following code does not work (Graph does not draw)

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {

    var data = [{"employee_no": "101","Salary": "1000"},{"employee_no": "102","Salary": "1500"},{"employee_no": "103","Salary": "1100"},{"employee_no": "104","Salary": "1900"},{"employee_no": "105","Salary": "1200"},
    {"employee_no": "106","Salary": "1800"},{"employee_no": "107","Salary": "2000"},{"employee_no": "108","Salary": "1500"}];

    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataLoader = data;
    chart.categoryField = "employee_no";

    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "Salary";
    graph.type = "line";
    graph.bullet = "round";
    graph.lineColor = "#8d1cc6";

    chart.addGraph(graph);

    chart.write('chartdiv');

    });
```

but if I use below code it works fine.

```
  chart.dataLoader = {
            url: "MY_URL",
            postProcess: function (data, options) {
                if (data === null) {
                    data = [];
                    options.chart.addLabel("50%", "50%", "No Data Available");
                }
                return data;
            }
        };
```

What is the error of above code ? I cannot figure it out.

Thanks you

Comment: You seem to be assigning data to `dataLoader`. If you don't want to load external data, you need to assign it directly to `dataProvider` instead.

Comment: Actually I am going to pass json object to javascript function and assign it to dataloader, before do that I tested it.. Then I faced this problem

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite understand your question. So do you have your data as a JSON object on your page already? If you do, you don't need Data Loader at all - it's meant only for loading external data.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you martynasma, You are right**

I have to use `chart.dataProvider` instead of `chart.dataLoader`

That solved my problem. We have to use `chart.dataLoader` only with http request.